# Canvas figure not showing title or axis format

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib

I am having a problem when ploting a graph inside my Main Window.

I am using QtDesigner for my Main Window.

Inside one of the horizontal_layout I want to disply a graph.

Here is the code that I am using to generate the plot:

```
def plotDistribution(dataToPlot, layout, numRows, nowCols):

    """ Delete previous elements in layout if any"""
    for i in reversed(range(layout.count())):
        layout.itemAt(i).widget().deleteLater()

    plt.ioff() 

    """ Extract data to plot """
    xdata = [i[0] for i in dataToPlot]
    ydata = [i[3] for i in dataToPlot]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    """ Format label ticks and values for X and Y"""
    xticksPos = np.arange(50,(100*numRows)+50,100)
    xticksVals = ["Row "+str(i) for i in np.arange(1,max(xdata),1) ]
    plt.xticks(xticksPos ,xticksVals ,rotation=90)

    yticksPos = np.arange(83,(166*numCols)+83,166)
    yticksVals = ["Column "+str(i) for i in np.arange(1,max(ydata),1) ]
    plt.yticks((yticksPos),(yticksVals))

    plt.title("Rows and Cols Distributuion")

    """ Create canvas and display in Main Window """
    MyCanvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    layout.addWidget(MyCanvas)

    plt.close(fig)
```

This program is called from Main Window, giving him some data to plot and the layout where I want the graph to be displayed.

However, if I call this same routine for more than one time, after the first time nothing is displayed in the title, nor in the axes.

I do not understand this rare behaviour.

Any help??

Comment: yes sorry, I will edit that

Comment: You should not, in general, mix the function API (plt.) with the object-oriented API of the qt-canvas. If you do want to, best to let matplotlib make a new window for each figure.

Comment: Hi mdurant, thanks for your comment, could you explain a bit more?, what I am doing wrong in this code?. As far as I know, If I don't do like this, I can't show the plot inside the Main Window.....Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the example http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4_wtoolbar.html you'll see there is no call to any plt.* functions. The pylab interface depends on a "current state", but you should be explicitly specifying each time which object is being affected.